# Unable to sign up for Azure (or add a subscription)

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Well, after going back and forth between various cloud services, we finally decided to use Microsoft Azure for some of our cloud needs.
And I must say, the initial experience hasn't been too encouraging. However I decided to seek advice before jumping ships :)

So I created an Organizational Account first and used my organizational email id. So far so good, then it again asks for my personal details, then credit card. I enter and MS successfully charges 1 dollar from my card. So the final step for singing up for Windows Azure is this screen:

[image: Final step for signing up for Azure]

However, after multiple attempts to complete the purchase spread over 10 hours and multiple browsers, all I get is this cryptic error:

[image: Error signing up for Azure]

I tried both the Free Plan and Pay as you Go Plan. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may submit a support ticket to Azure.

Comment: I understand that @Bruce, but its got to be telephonic support. As I don't have a subscription, I can't reach email support. My experience with telephonic support was not good yesterday, let's see how it goes tomorrow.